# MySQL self-join issue

Tags: sql, join

I have a source table "pairs":

```
    | r  |  x  | y  |
    | 1  | 20  | 20 |
    | 2  | 20  | 20 | 
    | 3  | 20  | 21 |
    | 4  | 21  | 20 |
    | 5  | 22  | 23 |
    | 6  | 23  | 22 |
```

After applying query with self-join

```
  select p1.r, p1.x, p2.y, p2.r
    from pairs p1 join pairs p2 on (p1.x = p2.y)
    order by p1.r;
```

I receive the result as expected:

```
r   x   y   r
1   20  20  1
1   20  20  2
1   20  20  4
2   20  20  1
2   20  20  2
2   20  20  4
3   20  20  1
3   20  20  2
3   20  20  4
4   21  21  3
5   22  22  6
6   23  23  5
```

In particular, for r=1, x=20 in one table is aligned (r=1, y=20),(r=2,y=20) and (r=4,y=20) in second table.

But when I apply the following join

```
select p1.r, p1.x, p2.y, p2.r
  from pairs p1 join pairs p2 on (p1.y = p2.x)
  order by p2.r, p1.r desc;
```

I receive something strange:

```
r   x   y   r
4   21  20  1
2   20  20  1
1   20  20  1
4   21  20  2
2   20  20  2
1   20  20  2
4   21  21  3
2   20  21  3
1   20  21  3
3   20  20  4
6   23  23  5
5   22  22  6
```

Taking first row, I cant understand, why for r=1, y=20 is aligned (r=4, x=21).
After all (y=20) < (x=21), which contradicts with join condition: p1.y = p2.x

Here is [sample](https://dbfiddle.uk/gDUi17eV)

Comment: `p1.x = p2.y` (in the `select` list) definitely must not hold when  `p1.y = p2.x`  (in `where`)

Comment: Debug questions require a [mre]--cut & paste & runnable code including initialization; desired & actual output (including verbatim error messages); tags & versions; clear specification & explanation. For SQL include DDL & tabular initialization code. For debug that includes the least code you can give that is code that you show is OK extended by code that you show is not OK. [ask] [Help] When you get a result you don't expect, pause your overall goal, chop to the 1st subexpression with unexpected result & say what you expected & why, justified by documentation. (Debugging fundamental.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is doing EXACTLY what you asked it to.

select p1.r, p1.x, p2.y, p2.r
from pairs p1 join pairs p2 on (p1.y = p2.x)
order by p2.r;

Your JOIN condition is based on p1.y = p2.x.  So, if we look at your original sample data

```
r    x    y
1    20   20 
2    20   20  
3    20   21 
4    21   20 
5    22   23 
6    23   22
```

Your OUTPUT columns of X and Y are reversed from the JOIN condition.

So, your resulting first line showing x=21 and y=20.  Look at the corresponding rows.

```
r   x   y   r
4   21  20  1

Row 4 = x=21,  y=20
Row 1 = x=20,  y=20
```

So, the Row4 y value of 20 IS equal to row1 x value of 20.  But you have the output pulling the row4 X value and row1 Y value hence the 21 and 20 as properly output.

If you changed your query to match the JOIN correlation, it would probably make more sense.

select p1.r, p1.`y`, p2.`x`, p2.r from...